# Template Template in C++ : <T, V<T> >

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to have a template class `Container` such that the item it contains and the way it is stored is both varied. Hence, I would like to be able to create `Container<int, Vector>`
(or `Container<int,  Vector<int> >` ? I'm not sure about which one is correct.), `Container<int, ArrayList>` etc., where `Vector` and `ArrayList` themselves are template classes.

What is the correct way of doing this? I understood that it is possible to have something like: `template <class T, template <class U> class V>`, but how do I ensure that the second parameter uses the first one as its first parameter in the template?

Edit: If this has been answered before do add the question as a comment here. I'll remove the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I ensure that the second parameter uses the first one as its first parameter in the template?

You use it that way.

This is a correct syntax:

```
template <class T, template <class U> class V>
class Container {
    using contain_type = V<T>;
};
```

but the parameter `U` is optional and doesn't declare any actual template parameter.  (Much like `void f(int* p);` is the same as `void f(int*);`, and the `p` in the first declaration doesn't declare any actual object.)

So you could just as well write:

```
template <class T, template <class> class V>
class Container {
    using contain_type = V<T>;
};
```

---

Pretty soon though, you'll probably run into a problem with the above declaration: you can't use it with `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::set`, etc.  This is because those are not templates with exactly one template parameter.  Thanks to default template arguments, `std::vector<int>` is really `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>`, `std::set<int>` is `std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int>>`, and so on.

To get around that you need the second parameter to match a variadic template:

```
template <class T, template<class...> class V>
class Container {
    using contain_type = V<T>;
};
```

This still only allows templates with only type parameters, but that's a lot better.

Now, for example, you can use `Container<int, std::vector>` as a type.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple answer depends on the fact that all containers from the standard library have a member `typedef` called `value_type`. Therefore, you can define your class template with only one type parameter:

```
template<typename T>
struct Container
{
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;
};
```

Whenever this is instantiated with a container from the standard library, it will know the `value_type` and you can just have fun:

```
::std::cout << sizeof(Container<::std::array<char, 1>>::value_type) << "\n"; // prints 1
::std::cout << sizeof(Container<::std::vector<short>>::value_type) << "\n"; // prints 2
::std::cout << sizeof(Container<::std::list<int>>::value_type) << "\n"; // prints 4
```